# Let $T$ and $T^{'}$ be topologies on set $X$ such that $T \leq T^{'}$. If $(X,T^{'})$ is path-connected, is $(X,T)$ path connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ and $T^{'}$ be topologies on set $X$ such that $T \leq T^{'}$. If $(X,T^{'})$ is path-connected, is $(X,T)$ path-connected?

I think it is, and I tried to prove it by contradiction, but I got stuck. Any hint helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, hint: consider the identity map $id:(X,T')\to(X,T)$.

Comment: The morale: any property preserved by continuous images (like connectedness, path connectedness, separability, Lindelöfness, compactness) is preserved by taking a finer topology.

Comment: ... you mean: "preserved by taking a *coarser* topology".  (T' is finer than T.)